# I don't fully understand a proof

Tags: matrices, proof-explanation, problem-solving

My problem is in understanding the last part, when $(x_i -y_j)(a_{ij}-b_{ij})=0$. It is suppose to imply $(a_{ij}-b_{ij})=0$ but I don't know why it can't be $(x_i -y_j)=0$. Please help.

**Lemma** Let $x_1, x_2, \dots x_n$ and $y_1, y_2, \dots y_n$ be real numbers. Let $A = (a_{ij})$ be an $n \times n$ matrix with entries $$a_{ij} = \left\{ \begin{array}{l l}
  1, & \textrm{if $x_i + y_j \ge 0$}\\
  0, & \textrm{else.}
\end{array} \right.$$
Let $B = (b_{ij})$ be an $n \times n$ matrix with entries $0$ or $1$ such that the sum of elements of each row and each column of $B$ equals to the corresponding sum for the matrix $A$. Show that $A = B$.

**Proof** 
Let 
\begin{align}
S &= \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n(x_i+y_j)(a_{ij} - b_{ij})\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^nx_i(a_{ij} - b_{ij})  + \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n y_j(a_{ij} - b_{ij})\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n x_i \sum_{j=1}^n(a_{ij} - b_{ij})  + \sum_{j=1}^n y_j\sum_{i=1}^n (a_{ij} - b_{ij})
= 0\\
\end{align}

because the row and column sums of $A$ and $B$ are the same.

On the other hand, using the definition of $a_{ij}$, we have

- When $x_i + y_j \ge 0$ the $a_{ij} - b_{ij} = 1 - b_{ij} \ge 0$
- When $x_i + y_j < 0$ the $a_{ij} - b_{ij} = - b_{ij} \le 0$

So, $(x_i + y_j)(a_{ij} - b_{ij}) \ge 0$ for all $i, j$. Since $S = 0$, then $(x_i + y_j)(a_{ij} - b_{ij}) = 0$ for all $i, j$, and $a_{ij} = b_{ij}$ for all $i, j$, and we are done.

$\square$

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures cannot be searched and are inaccessible to those using screen readers.

Comment: For future uses (please not here): taking a screenshot normally leads to better image quality than this.

Comment: Sorry but it's too large I'll write it when I have time. If someone cannot see it properly just wait.

Comment: I already did it, it's in the queue for approval. I changed one line because i thought it was a typo, you can change it back if it wasn't.

Comment: I was doing it now but thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. The proof is too short. Let $i$ be fixed and let $J = \{j : x_i+y_j= 0\}$. Then $a_{ij} = b_{ij}$ for all $j\notin J$. Therefore,
$$
|J| = \sum_{j\in J}a_{ij} = \sum_ja_{ij} - \sum_{j\notin J}a_{ij} = \sum_jb_{ij} - \sum_{j\notin J}b_{ij} = \sum_{j\in J}b_{ij}.
$$
Hence, $b_{ij} = a_{ij} = 1$ also for all $j\in J$. Listo! ;o)

Comment: What you proved there is that all the non-matching entries in a row or in a column must sum up the same. But how does it implies they are all equal?

Comment: They are all either 0 or 1... Can there be a zero in the $b_{ij}$'s that sum up to $|J|$?

Comment: I don't know what you mean but consider this example: 1,0,0,0,1,1,0(A) and 0,1,0,0,0,1,1(B) the entries which have changed are the 1,2,5,7 and $|J|=4$ and it achieves the property you've written but they are not equal. Maybe I've misunderstood what you've written

Comment: I assume that your matrices are 1x7. Well, they have the same row sum, but the column sums differ from each other.

Comment: It's simple. In the equation in my answer you have a sum of $|J|$ zeros and/or ones that equals $|J|$. There is thus no other possibility that all summands equal one.